# Is casting to an interface a boxing conversion?

Tags: c#, oop, boxing

I have an interface IEntity

```
public interface IEntity{
    bool Validate();
}
```

And I have a class Employee which implements this interface

```
public class Employee : IEntity{
    public bool Validate(){ return true; }
}
```

Now if I have the following code

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
IEntity ent1 = (IEntity)emp1; // Is this a boxing conversion?
```

If it is not a boxing conversion then how does the cast work?

Comment: In this case, the cast is not required. Employee implements the IEntity interface, so you can freely assign a reference to IEntity (ent1 in your example) to any reference of Employee (again since it implements the IEntity interface) without requiring an explicit cast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, since `Employee` is a class, which is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) rather than a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx):

> Boxing is the process of converting a
>   value type  to the type object or to
>   any interface type implemented by this
>   value type. When the CLR boxes a value
>   type, it wraps the value inside a
>   System.Object and stores it on the
>   managed heap. Unboxing extracts the
>   value type from the object.

The aforementioned MSDN link has further examples that should help clarify the topic.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying the fact that although it isn't in the actual example the OP shows, it *may be* in a different situation.

Answer (score 9):

In your example above, no but sometimes yes.

Boxing is the process of "boxing" a value type into a referenceable object; a reference type. In your example above, Employee is already a reference type, so it is not boxed when you cast it to IEntity.

However, had Employee been a value type, such as a struct (instead of a class), then yes.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, casting a reference type to an interface is NOT an example of boxing, but casting a Value Type to an interface IS.

```
public interface IEntity {
    bool Validate();
}

public class EmployeeClass : IEntity {
    public bool Validate() { return true; }
}

public struct EmployeeStruct : IEntity {
    public bool Validate() { return true; }
}


//Boxing: A NEW reference is created on the heap to hold the struct's memory. 
//The struct's instance fields are copied into the heap.
IEntity emp2 = new EmployeeStruct(); //boxing

//Not considered boxing: EmployeeClass is already a reference type, and so is always created on the heap. 
//No additional memory copying occurs.
IEntity emp1 = new EmployeeClass(); //NOT boxing

//unboxing: Instance fields are copied from the heap into the struct. 
var empStruct = (EmployeeStruct)emp2;
//empStruct now contains a full shallow copy of the instance on the heap.


//no unboxing. Instance fields are NOT copied. 
var empClass = (EmployeeClass)emp2; //NOT unboxing.
//empClass now points to the instance on the heap.
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples! Helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No.

Because emp1 is a reference type.

Boxing occurs when a value type is converted to an object, or an interface type.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

Your instance of Employee is already a Reference Type. Reference Types are stored on the Heap so it doesn't need to be boxed/unboxed.

Boxing only occurs when you store a Value Type on the Heap or, in MSDN language, you could say:

> Boxing is an implicit conversion of a
>   Value Types (C# Reference) to the type
>   object or to any interface type
>   implemented by this value type. Boxing
>   a value type allocates an object
>   instance on the heap and copies the
>   value into the new object.

Answer (score 0):

No, boxing occurs when you convert a value type to an object.

Comment: I think you mean to have a comma ',' after the first word in your brief reply. Without this--that is, as your reply currently stands--it has the opposite meaning, and is thus incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Boxing means converting a value type to object. You are converting a reference type to another reference type, so this is not a boxing conversion.